# Copying from a complex file directory with rsync

Tags: linux, file-transfer, rsync

I have a complex file directory such as the one below.

- Top_directory

  - Dir1

    - Dir2

      - File1
      - File2
      - Dir3

        - File3
        - File4
        - File5 > ../File1 (symbolic link)
      - Dir4
      - Dir5
    - Dir6
    - Dir7

I have a list of files in a text file such as:

```
/Top_directory/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3
```

What I want is this:

Reading from the text file I want to copy everything inside Dir3 but symbolic link should be kept (It should copy File1 in Dir2 and a link as File5). I also want to copy all the files in between the top directory and Dir3 (File2 in this case). But I don't want Dir4 and Dir5 Dir6 and Dir7 (basically the directories not included in the text file). rsync was the most promising option but I cannot use include exclude options because there are many more directories than given. So it should be like this at the destination folder:

- Top_directory

  - Dir1

    - Dir2

      - File1
      - File2
      - Dir3

        - File3
        - File4
        - File5 > ../File1 (symbolic link)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You'll need a simple script to do that. For each path in your text file, build the destination path by chopping Top_directory off the beginning, and rsync that path with --mkpath (if you have a recent rsync; otherwise run mkdir -p with the dirname on the destination). Then use find $path -type l | xargs realpath to find the referents of all the symlinks in Dir3, and rsync them using the same process of building a dest path first. Hopefully that's enough to get you started.